# VBA pickup value from specific header and use it in line

Tags: vba

Hello I'm trying to read an excel file and convert it to file with no spaces (managed to do - see my code), also the part I need help is where before my block of data there is a header/tag with the period name,  which I need to read and use it in my lines. Any help would be great.
Thank you.

```
Sub Convert_Journal()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Const NoLines As Integer = 1000
    Dim i&

    Columns("A:I").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("target").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    For i = NoLines To 1 Step -1
       If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A" & i, "I" & i)) < 9 Then
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
       End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

[SOURCE FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acr6N.png)
    [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acr6N.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wq2ql.png

[TARGET FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acr6N.png)